# Link static library conditionally in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

Recently I started using a library (TestFlight) for testing purposes.

I wonder how can I make Xcode to link that `library.a` with the debug and adhoc configurations only? This library is about 2.5MB so I don't want it to be there when I push my app the ApStore.

BTW : Now I am *only* compiling things conditionally by defining `TESTFLIGHT` in the preprocessor macros:

```
 #ifdef TESTFLIGHT
...
 #endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting up a special build target that is just for the App Store. Ad Hoc profiles are actually app store profiles just with the additional information that it is provisioned for.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following answer for you lib files.

Use following commands for checking architecture support for ur lib:

`cd <path to library folder> # in you case: /Users/alexis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PlazappPartnerWorkspace-            cdrmloavlcqouugawmtqywiinqne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
    lipo -info libPlazappPartnerLib.a`